# Terminal will not allow SSH to Linux

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, terminal, vps

I have a VPS that I have accessed using Terminal in the past. When I open Terminal I get

Last login: Tue Aug 29 04:02:48 on ttys002
Mac-mini:~ administator$

All of the articles I have been able to google say use

ssh username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

This returns permission denied when I enter the password (I am 100% sure the password and username are correct). I know the reason is because Terminal is not reaching out of the Mac. In the past I found a command that needs to be entered before you can enter "ssh username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx". It is as if I have to enter a command to exit the Macs' localhost then enter the ssh server information.

My question is does anyone know what the command is? I have scoured the Googles and am unable to find the information I found before and my bookmarked page has been taken down.

Thank You!!

Comment: The terminal does not disallow outbound traffic, nor does anything in macOS. Only *inbound* traffic is filtered or blocked, either by your hardware firewall (typically a router in SOHO) and/or your software firewall in macOS/OS X, should you enable it.

Comment: Please run the ssh command in verbose mode (`ssh -v username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`) and give us the output. Don't forget to remove  confidential information first. Also, the IP address you are trying to reach should not be like 192.168.xxx.xxx or 10.0.xxx.xxx .

Comment: ...have you tried from another location? It sounds to me like your public IP has been blocked on the VPS server-side from failed password attempts.

Comment: Where is the VPS hosted, in AWS?

Comment: You are either using public key authentication, in which case you're missing `ssh-add`, or you need to supply SSH with a PEM file

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the VPS is hosted on AWS, the missing command you speak of would be the path to the access-file (.PEM) file. For example:
`ssh -i path/to/AccessKey.pem ubuntu@ec2-12-34-567-890.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

Detailed info here: https://99robots.com/how-to-ssh-to-ec2-instance-on-aws/

Answer (score 0):

If you use ssh from the Mac Terminal you'll intend to connect to a remote server running sshd (ssh daemon).

For this to happen some things should be OK:

- you should be on a network ( you got an IP address and router,  DNS is helpful)
- the remote server should be on a network
- these networks should interconnect in a way that traffic is possible. `netstat -nr` will show the routing table on osx, linux and windows (provided netstat is permitted) `traceroute` and `ping` might help, but on the internet these are usually blocked.
- if you work in a company then ssh might not be permitted.
- the remote server might not allow it
- any network in between might not allow it

If all of the above are OK then you can try `telnet server 22` assuming it runs on the standard port, and that Sierra is latest OSX. This will reveal tcp connectivity.

Now comes ssh. Both sides should agree on all kinds of details.

- PasswordAuthentication is likely switched off, or the password might be stored in a directory server.
- you should not connect as the root user
- an alternative Authentication mechanism should be used, a key-pair is very common, but tokens, certificates, one-time passwords,  kerberos are possible. We don't know but your hosting partner will. Key pairs are used by default. AWS and GCE have their own ways, each has instructional pages.
- you should be allowed access to ssh and its files on your Mac and these file should have restrictive file permissions.
- you should be able to add the ip address to ~/.ssh/known_hosts
- if ssh keys on your Mac are in the (hidden) directory .ssh in your home directory. Use `ssh-keygen` to create a pair and send the pub file to the administrator.
- if you are the local admin then you should add the pub file to the authorized_keys file for the linux user that needs to be logged  onto. A console session is needed if no-one can use ssh. Its file location mentioned in the sshd_config file, normally $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys.

More arcane cases exist, like incompatible ciphers and mismatching versions, but if both ends are up to date the above should help you find the problem. If not you need help from the inside, i.e. root on your sshd server can `tail -f /var/log/secure`.